# Mockito's deep-stub mocking doesn't do well when lambda arguments are involved. Why?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

Look at this test. It freezes and doesn't complete in a reasonable amount of time (if at all). Don't ask me what it tests. It tests nothing: it's an MRE of the problem I want to show you

```java
package com.example.dynamicgateway.service.applicationDocClient;

import io.swagger.v3.parser.OpenAPIV3Parser;
import io.swagger.v3.parser.core.models.SwaggerParseResult;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
import reactor.test.StepVerifier;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

public class WebClientTest {
    @Test
    void test() {
        OpenAPIV3Parser parserMock = mock(OpenAPIV3Parser.class);
        SwaggerParseResult parseResultMock = mock(SwaggerParseResult.class);
        WebClient webClientMock = mock(WebClient.class, RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
        when(webClientMock
                .get()
                .uri("https://example.com/docs")
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class)
                .map(parserMock::readContents)
        ).thenReturn(Mono.just(parseResultMock));

        Mono<SwaggerParseResult> stringMono = webClientMock
                .get()
                .uri("https://example.com/docs")
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class)
                .map(parserMock::readContents);

        StepVerifier.create(stringMono)
                .expectNext(parseResultMock)
                .expectComplete()
                .verify();
    }
}
```

I figured it has to do with the lambda (it doesn't matter if it's a method reference or not). If I run this test, it passes:

```java
    @Test
    void test() {
        String responseString = "response-string";
        WebClient webClientMock = mock(WebClient.class, RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
        when(webClientMock
                .get()
                .uri("https://example.com/docs")
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class)
        ).thenReturn(Mono.just(responseString));

        Mono<String> stringMono = webClientMock
                .get()
                .uri("https://example.com/docs")
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class);

        StepVerifier.create(stringMono)
                .expectNext(responseString)
                .expectComplete()
                .verify();
    }
```

It doesn't matter if the lambda uses a mock or not. This freezes too:

```java
    @Test
    void test() {
        WebClient webClientMock = mock(WebClient.class, RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
        String uri = "https://example.com";
        Integer expectedInt = 42;
        when(webClientMock
                .get()
                .uri(uri)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class)
                .map(Integer::valueOf)
        ).thenReturn(Mono.just(expectedInt));

        Mono<Integer> integerMono = webClientMock
                .get()
                .uri(uri)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class)
                .map(Integer::valueOf);

        StepVerifier.create(integerMono)
                .expectNext(expectedInt)
                .expectComplete()
                .verify();
    }
```

Why is it happening? What should I do instead? You may need to mock method chains involving a `WebClient` every now and then – chains that may accept an occasional lambda

In this particular case, it could be fixed rather easily (see the snippet below). But what about more complex cases where the chain is longer, and lambda arguments are all over it?

```java
    @Test
    void test() {
        SwaggerParseResult parseResultMock = mock(SwaggerParseResult.class);
        String serializedParseResult = serialize(parseResultMock);

        OpenAPIV3Parser parserMock = mock(OpenAPIV3Parser.class);
        when(parserMock.readContents(serialziedParseResult)).thenReturn(parseResultMock);

        WebClient webClientMock = mock(WebClient.class, RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
        when(webClientMock
                .get()
                .uri("https://example.com/docs")
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class)
        ).thenReturn(Mono.just(serialziedParseResult));

        Mono<SwaggerParseResult> parseResultMono = webClientMock
                .get()
                .uri("https://example.com/docs")
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class)
                .map(parserMock::readContents);

        StepVerifier.create(parseResultMono)
                .expectNext(parseResultMock)
                .expectComplete()
                .verify();
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    private String serialize(SwaggerParseResult parseResult) {
        return new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(parseResult);
    }
```

Java 17, Spring Boot 3.2.1, `spring-boot-starter-test`. The `WebClient` specifically is from `org.springframework:spring-webflux:6.1.2`

Comment: Which version of `org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient` are you using -- the relevant dependencies from your pom would help.

Comment: @tgdavies `spring-webflux:6.1.2`

Comment: Lambdas can't be compared for equality, so Mockito can't verify that they're passed as arguments.  The correct solution is to either not assert which lambdas are passed, or not to mock in the first place, and test with more conventional tools, such as testing methods for their effects.